# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MyObjectViewDelegate' when it is CLEARLY there ?1

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, protocols

I have a class like this..

```
#import "MyObjectAddView.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

#define myAppDelegate (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

@class MyObjectAddView;

@interface AccountViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, MyObjectAddViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

    MyObjectAddView *myAddView;
    .....
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyObjectAddView *myAddView;

- (id) initWithSettings:(SettingsObject *)settings;

@end
```

WHY is it suddenly telling me that it **Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MyObjectAddViewDelegate'** when I'm clearly importing and including the @class for where the protocol is defined? Here how *MyObjectAddView* setup:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

#define myAppDelegate (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

@protocol MyObjectAddViewDelegate;

@interface MyObjectAddView : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate> {

@private
    id <MyObjectAddViewDelegate> delegate;
    ....    
@public
    .....
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id <MyObjectAddViewDelegate> delegate;
.....

@end

@protocol MyObjectAddViewDelegate <NSObject>
// expense == nil on cancel
- (void)myObjectAddViewDidFinish:(MyObjectAddView *)addView;

@end
```

Everything seems perfectly setup and I don't see any circular imports ?! Any suggestions why it might not be seeing the protocol definition in MyObjectAddView?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your included files.<br>
This is symptom of two mutually included headers.<br>
Sometimes it cause this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need a forward reference to a class after you have imported the header for that class. Only time you do a forward reference is if you plan on including the header inside of the implementation file. Remove `@class MyObjectAddView` and if that fixes it let me know if not I may have another solution for you.

Comment: I need the forward reference otherwise it crashes on the line `MyObjectAddView *myAddView` saying _expected specifier-qualifier-list before MyObjectAddView_ which I have no idea what it means. That error goes away if I include the forward reference as well. So removing it does not fix the issue. Removing it still says that it cannot find the protocol declaration. hmm

Comment: That seems odd. There may be something else going on. I am guessing your second code sample is MyObjectAddView.h and if that is the case you should not need to include a forward declaration in the first code example because you clearly import it. It may be possible that although the header file is in your project maybe it is in an incorrect directory and therefore not in the header search path.

Comment: problem resolved. I said there was no cyclical imports going on but there actually was with #import "MyAppDelegate.h" inside all classes. Issue resolved. Thanks for enlightening me on the when @class is needed and not.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. It was kind of funny to me that was your issue because I was thinking to myself wow is he really adding that same code to all of his header files to access the delegate :)

Comment: I may have jumped to conclusions saying that would fix his problem but I can not agree with you that it is **totally harmless** to have a forward declaration after you have imported the file. I said that you do not need a forward declaration after an import and that is true. If you do add one no big deal, but in a situation like Straddle's all that the forward declaration do was cover up another issue he was having. Since he happened to try and reference a protocol from the same class he got an additional error. Best practice I would say is to only include a forward reference when necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Synthesizing the discussion: another solution is to check for cyclical imports between the delegate implementation and protocol declaration. This solved my issue.